# How to add image to UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-graphics

I'm trying to add image to `UIImageView`, but after I do it `UIImageView` is nil. Here's my code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testImg: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 500,height: 500))
                var path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = 1.0
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150))
        var x = 151
        for ;x<300;x++
        {
            path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: x))
            path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: x))
        }
        path.stroke()
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                testImg = UIImageView(image: img)
        testImg.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 500,height: 500)
        myView.addSubview(testImg)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

When I try to set frame for `UIImageView`, I got this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Probably, i don't create image correctly.

UPDATE

```
testImg = UIImageView(image: img)
```

This line of code overwrites `IBOutlet` of `UIImageView`, removing it and doing simply 
`testImg.image = img`
fixed problem.

Comment: Did you connect the outlet?

Comment: Yes, both outlets are connected

Comment: Is the storyboard ViewController class is set up in the identity inspector?

Comment: Yes, it is set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
if let image = img {
    // you don't have to instantiate an imageView again, IBOutlet handles it for you    
    testImg.image = image
    print("Works")
    // if you don't see this output in your debug console, the condition never succeeds and an img is really nil
}
```

Comment: isn't it the same?
`testImg = UIImageView(image: img)`

Comment: added if block, same error when setting image property

Comment: By `testImg = UIImageView(image: img)` you were rewriting your original IBOutlet by your new UIImageView from scratch.

Comment: So did my answer help you? :)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot) I marked it as an answer long ago)

Answer (score 2):

Easy way : Drag and drop that image to your file view/project navigator on Xcode.

Select the image view - Then attribute inspect - Under image - Select the file name of the image you wish to load.

Enjoy the drags and drops whenever you can.

Hardway:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imageName", ofType:     "jpg"), let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath) {    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: I don't have a file, i'm creating image via UIBezierPath

Comment: You mean i can't create image via code and add it to UIImageView?

Comment: Apologies, I was going to say can't help there.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be related to the way you push or present the `ViewController`. Seems the outlet is not created yet when you show or present it. Should use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` as below example

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourStoryBoardId")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
```

Comment: i have only one view, added these two strings after `super.viewDidLoad()`, nothing changed. i think it's a problem with UIImageView